# Take [action] out of action

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Today I noticed that we have an [action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/action) (2883) tag. Going through the first page:

- [skip around_filter with argument & block rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748464/skip-around-filter-with-argument-block-rails)
- [SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified (jquery in mvc 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634813/syntaxerror-an-invalid-or-illegal-string-was-specified-jquery-in-mvc-5)
- [Multithreading - how to invoke Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629513/multithreading-how-to-invoke-action) (C#)
- [Can I have more actions in a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29631976/can-i-have-more-actions-in-a-form) (PHP)
- [Invoke programatically iOS App Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535831/invoke-programatically-ios-app-extensions)

And many, many more. This tag apparently means that something is doing something, or essentially all of programming.

Answering the questions in [Shog's burnination guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

- **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?** No. Something is doing something or needs to be done. Not unambigious.
- **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?** Yes... in theory.
- **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?** No.
- **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?** No. It means different things at different times in different languages.

If there's something about this tag I'm missing that makes it acceptable, great! Otherwise, can we kill it?

Comment: /OT: I really don't understand why so many tag burinating requests, have those _funny puns_ in their title?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I view it primarily as a way to break the monotony of six thousand "Burninate [tag]" titles. There are pros and cons to each approach :)

Comment: Action is pretty core in [java] and [c#], probably some more.  Entirely unambiguous in those tags and an excellent contextual tag for the kind of question.  Please don't kill a tag that many programmers need to use to draw interest to their question and match the right kind of language expert, just a bare [java] doesn't cut it.

Comment: I agree with @Hans. The tag has 26 followers. I think this might be a case of _some_ misuse going on which could be countered by correcting those mistags and improving the tag wiki.

Comment: @HansPassant there's a difference between "it could be useful" and "it's useful". This tag is on all views and context worthless in both practice and theory. When you try to defend a tag, at least make sure that everyone using the tag will actually use it correctly. **A misused tag, is a worthless tag.**

Comment: I don't get the point of that argument.  There is no might, it **is** useful.  To 329 Java programmers that asked a question about the Action interface and 277 C# programmers that asked about a Action delegate.  Etcetera, I didn't look at them all.  Language and framework designers don't pay attention to SO tags, they pick a word that is memorable, common and descriptive.  Nobody thinks long about the word to describe an exception, they of course use [exception].  So it has twenty thousand questions across different languages.  Same here, no need to torture anybody to come up with another word

Comment: Couldn't the tag be made more specific to those Java/C# programmers who use it in a specific context, thus removing the pollution coming from other contexts?  E.g. c#-action, java-action.

Comment: That is **never** a problem either, it already is highly specific.  A Java programmer uses the [java] tag on his question, a C# programmer tags [c#].  Everybody does that, you have seen it being done.  SO users apply the OR operator to find help, they get it from users that apply AND to the tags before they take a look at the question.  The distinction between the two is what keeps all these meta questions about tag burnination going forever :)  There is no logical operator for the kind of nirwana that @Braiam likes.  Other than DELETE.

Comment: @HansPassant no, if there's a unambiguous tag that could be used, you should use it. This tag as it's doesn't meet the criteria to be a successful tag. Just look at the kind of questions it gets... I found questions which only relationship with "action" as Java or C# defines them is.... the name!

Comment: And the DELETE operator is a pretty nasty one, it creates islands of programmers that can't find each other anymore and can't learn from each other.  I personally get the most benefit out of SO from applying the ORMAYBE operator.  A fantastic one to combine things I do know with things I might (and do) want to know about.  Worth a lot, the occasional misuse of a tag is but a blip on my learning curve.  Never stop learning, it is death.

Comment: @HansPassant then, answer Shog's questions the same way Undo did.

Answer (score -1):

> skip around_filter with argument & block rails

Something to do with Ruby on Rails

> SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified (jquery in mvc 5)

Umm... jQuery, ASP.NET, what?

> Multithreading - how to invoke Action (C#)

C#

> Can I have more actions in a form? (PHP)

It couldn't be other thing but PHP?

> Invoke programatically iOS App Extensions

Smelling Objetive-C question mayhap?

---

Yeah, this tag is all over the place. It doesn't provide "context" beyond actioning something (and the iOS question was trying to identify his app as "action app", whatever that may be, is not the correct use of the tag according to the excerpt). It seems that all questions that has that tag in someplace has the "action" keyword, yet is not relevant to the question in any way or form.

It's just filling space that would be useful for other tags, so let it burn.